# Generate random modal with one button click - React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm developing a project for myself, in React Native. I have a button that can open up two modals at the same time. However I need it to randomize between the two, so there's a 50/50 percent chance it'll open up either one.

I've tried searching for a solution for hours.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do something like that: `const redOrBlue = Math.random() ... if (Math.random(<0.5) { render Modal 1} else {render modal 2}`. You can do it JSX `{ redOrBlue < 0.5 ? <ModalComponent1 /> : <ModalComponent2 /> }` PSEUDOCODE